# Ubuntu - Failed to stop postgres.service: Unit postgres.service not loaded

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I tried to stop postgres with the command `systemctl stop postgres` and I got this error. Now I can't start postgres in a docker container because the port is already used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed, I had to use the command `systemctl stop postgresql` instead of `systemctl stop postgres`.